# How can I allow only administrators to shutdown a program in windows

Tags: wpf, windows, security

I dont know if this has to do with how the program is programmed or how it is set up or how it is started.

But I created a program in WPF and I would like to make sure that none of he regular users on the computer shut it down.

The regular users need to be able to interact with it but they should not be able to close it.

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago, and I have the source at home.  Email me (from my profile) in 8 hours & I'll dig it up.

Comment: How is the program started?  Does a non-admin user launch it manually? Task scheduler?  Run keys in the registry?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I could use any of those methods if it will give me the desired results. Whats your idea?

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach would be to run the application as a service with permissions set by the administrator to not let the user manipulate the service. Otherwise you will run into trouble with user-initiated shutdown and with preventing the application from being terminated.

Comment: My question said that I need the users to interact with it. It needs a graphical interface.

Comment: @Rabbi Build a GUI that interacts with the service. Service becomes the data provider and any routines that must be running. And the App communicates with it and displays data through a GUI that allows editing.

Comment: @Rabbi: This is the best approach.  I didn't use it because it takes more effort.

Comment: @Xaade and how do I prevent them from closing the GUI?

Comment: You can make the service automatically restart the GUI if it closes.

Comment: You can also set the ACL of the GUI process to deny close access.  (this was my approach; it's not quite bulletproof)

Comment: @Rabbi one of benefits of splitting the GUI and the service is that the service can monitor that the UI is shut down by the user and restart it (even when the UI process is killed forcefully). Restarting is tricky, but possible.

Comment: @Rabbi Are you trying to ensure that the user can't access the OS? If so, why not create a shell replacer? If you don't want access to be prevented, then why have the GUI always visible. The only other reason is to ensure a process stays alive for background processing purpose, at which point let the user relaunch the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that the OP wants to prevent visibility of the OS, creating a terminal like experience. The best way to do this is to create a shell replacement.

Then the user wouldn't see the OS as windows directly.